# Show that $P(|X_n| > an \text{ for infinitely many } n) = 1$ for any $a > 0$ with $E[|X_n|] = ∞$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I want to check my solutions for this problem. Can someone help me?

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables.

Suppose $E[|X_n|] = ∞$.

a. Show that $P(|X_n| > an \text{ for infinitely many } n) = 1$ for any $a > 0$. Hint: Justify $\int_{0}^{\infty} P(|X_1| > at) dt = ∞$ and then use $P(|X_n| > an) > P(|X_n| > at)$ for $t > n$.

My solutions:

First, let's justify $\int_{0}^{\infty} P(|X_1| > at) dt = ∞$.

We know that $E[|X_1|] = ∞ = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq t) dt$ for positive $X_1$.

So, we have $E[|X_1|] = ∞ = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq t) dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(|X_1| \geq t) dt$.

We also know that $E[|aX_1|] = aE[|X_1|]$ for positive $a$.

Therefore, $aE[|X_1|] = \infty = a \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq t) dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq at) dt = E[|aX_1|] = \infty$.

Now, we can use the hint that $P(|X_n| > an) > P(|X_n| > at)$, and since $\int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq at) dt = \infty$, it implies that $P(X_1 \geq at) = 1$. Therefore, $P(X_1 \geq an) = 1$ follows from $P(|X_n| > an) > P(|X_n| > at)$ for $t > n$.

Are my solutions correct?

Comment: Where does $P(X_1 \geq at) = 1$ come from?

Comment: Use the second Borel Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: @geetha290krm isnt $P(X_1 \geq at)$ equivalent to $E[aX_1]$?

Comment: @darkgbm is my solution not right?

Comment: $E|aX_1|=\int_0^{\infty} P(|X_1| \geq  at)dt=\infty$ is correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm and so why can I not prove the Hint with $aE[|X_1|] = \infty = a \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq t) dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq at) dt = E[|aX_1|] = \infty$ ?Since we know that $E[|X_n|]= \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in the last part and you did not even prove what was asked.

Integrate $P(|X_n| > an) \geq P(|X_1| > at)$ from $t=n$ to $t=n+1$ and add. You get $\sum_n P(|X_n| > an) \geq \int_0^{\infty} P(|X_1| \geq  at)dt=\infty$.  The conclusion now follows by the converse part of Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: Why is $\sum_n P(|X_n| > an) \geq \int_0^{\infty} P(|X_1| \geq  at)dt$ ?

Comment: When you integrate from $n$ to $n+1$ LHS does not change. The integrals from $n$ to $n+1$ add up to integral from $0$ to $\infty$. @MarcoDiGiacomo

Comment: Okay but than with borel cantelli we have $P(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup (|X_n| \geq an))=1$ and not $P(|X_n| \geq an)=1 $ @geetha290krm

Comment: B-C lemma says that if $\sum P(A_n)=\infty$ and $A_n$'s are independent then $P (A_n \text {infinitely often})=1$.

Comment: and so why can I not prove the Hint with $aE[|X_1|] = \infty = a \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq t) dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 \geq at) dt = E[|aX_1|] = \infty$ since we know $E[|X_n|]= \infty$?

Comment: You have correctly proved he first part of the hint. My comments are not about the hints but only about the last part of your solution. @MarcoDiGiacomo

Comment: okay but$ \int_{0}^{\infty}P(|X_1| \geq at)dt= \infty$ doesnt mean that the probability $P(|X_1| \geq at)=1$ ? @geetha290krm

Comment: Certainly not! $t$ is the variable of integration. It is not a constant. @MarcoDiGiacomo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147122/discussion-between-marco-di-giacomo-and-geetha290krm).